# Tempo de sessão do utilizador

Tags: php

Boas comunidade.
Quando o utilizador faz login eu adiciono na base de dados o dia e hora que este utilizador logou.

O ficheiro `init.php`, que contém o inicio de sessão e o qual eu uso em todas as minhas páginas eu coloquei o seguinte código:

```
if(($_SESSION['last_login'])>2){
//echo "ok";
}else{

header("location: logout.php?timeout=1");
}
```

Agora, eu queria que o utilizador depois de 30minutos fosse redirecionado para a página de logout. Estarei a fazer de forma correta? Formato da data `2016-01-29 14:19:45`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não vejo a necessidade de gravar em `banco de dados`, use somente variáveis de sessão. Aqui vai um exemplo simples fazendo isso em 30 segundos:

**login.php**

```
<?php

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['start_login'])) { // se não tiver pego tempo que logou
    $_SESSION['start_login'] = time(); //pega tempo que logou
    // adiciona 30 segundos ao tempo e grava em outra variável de sessão
    $_SESSION['logout_time'] = $_SESSION['start_login'] + 30; 
}

// se o tempo atual for maior que o tempo de logout
if(time() >= $_SESSION['logout_time']) { 
    header("location:logout.php"); //vai para logout
    session_destroy();
} else {
    $red = $_SESSION['logout_time'] - time(); // tempo que falta
    echo "Início de sessão: ".$_SESSION['start_login']."<br>";
    echo "Redirecionando em ".$red." segundos.<br>";
}

?>
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php

echo "logout\n<br>";
session_start();
session_destroy();

?>
<a href="login.php">Voltar</a>
```

Para colocar 30 `minutos` coloque `30 * 60`.

Comment: No meu caso, coloco o seu pedaço de código no meu init.php, que é a página que está sempre presente em todas as outras, sim? O meu ficheiro login só corre quando o utilizador faz o login.

Comment: @Ivcs Coloquei no meu init.php mas ele não esta enviando o utilizador para o logout.php. o `echo` do código deu isto: `Início de sessão: 1454174519`
`Redirecionando em 30 segundos.`

Comment: Para isso eu deveria ver a estrutura de arquivos. Se o init está em todas as páginas pode colocar o código lá. Verifique se o `logout.php` está na mesma pasta do init, se não altere o caminho do `header`. E verifique se recarregou ou trocou de página depois que o tempo de 30 segundos se passou, pois o php não verifica isso em tempo real, apenas quando há um refresh.

Comment: @Ivcs perfeito amigo :) coloquei na página init.php Obrigado :)

Answer (score 0):

O PHP já possui um parametro `session.gc_maxlifetime`, que pode ser alterado.

**Edite o PHP.ini:**

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1800
```

Isso irá fazer expirar a sessão após 1800 segundos (30 minutos).

**Verifique se existe a sessão:**

Dessa forma apenas verifique se existe a sessão:

```
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['sua_sessao'])){
// Se houver sessão - OK
}else{
header('location: logout.php');
// Se não houver - Redireciona para logout.php
}

?>
```

A sessão irá expirar em 30 minutos e irá redirecionar para logout.php.

**Problemas e correções:**

Suponha que um usuário NUNCA fez o login, se ele acessar a página será redirecionado para logout.php, porque também não possui sessão, o que no meu entender seria errado.

Por isso crie um cookie quando fizer o login e verifique da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

//...
}else{

if(isset($_COOKIE['login'])){
// Se existe o cookie, que já indica que o usuário já se conectou alguma vez
    header('location: logout.php');
    // Redireciona para logout.
}else{
// Se o visitante caiu de paraquedas na página e nunca fez o login
    header('location: login.php');
    // Redireciona para o login.
}

?>
```